# send large json object as response is takes long time in express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using: node, express, routing-controllers

when i try to response large json object, it takes more than 60s.
there is my code :

```
@Get("/")
getAll() {
    return db.get('phones')
}
```

if i response the same json file , it takes only a few  second.
there is my code :

```
@Get("/")
getAll(@Req() request: any, @Res() response: any) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject)  => {
            return  (response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../db/phones.json")));
    })
}
```

How can i solve it in a better way?

(I don't wont to use in lazy loading)

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: is it just your db running slow query or low connection speed?

Comment: Why do you wrap it in a promise? Just return response.sendFile(path....)

Comment: the file size is 2.3 m.

Comment: so, your db query pulls out 2.3mb of data? No wonder it takes a while!

Comment: is in a promise , because i am using routing-controllers . there is only example. the question is why response json it takes to long. maybe it's compress problem?

Comment: xShirase , there is no db issues, i add break in the result from db, it takes no time at all. (nedb -  from memory....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the same data takes a few seconds when not queried from the DB, it is safe to assume that the issue lies with your db query.

Most db issues can be solved by proper indexing. Try running your query independently, see how long it takes, then add relevant indexes and the speed will increase dramatically. In your case, keep in mind that your query needs to pull 2.3Mb of data OUT of the db, before sending those 2.3Mb to the client. In all likelihood, you're better off with a file anyway.

If you're sure that the db isn't the issue, get rid of the promise in your code, and try : `response.send(db.get('phones'))`

Comment: No, there is no db issue. I checked it.

Comment: how long does the db query take to return?

Answer (score 0):

xShirase solve my problem.
there is my new code :

```
@Get("/")
getAll(@Req() request: any, @Res() response: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
    db.get('phones').then(phones => {
        response.send(phones)})
    })
}
```

I just used the example from https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers.

[image]